# Installation of a program by using the terminal on MAC OS X

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, dmg-image

I have just started to work on a Mac terminal for a school work.

My question is: which commands do I have to write to install a program (if I have the .dmg file) by using the terminal only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need `hdiutil` to mount the disk image.
- If your installation is done with mac packages, then use `installer`
- If your installation is drag and drop, then use `install`

The manuals are quite extensive. Please read them all carefully.